# Initializing initial capacity and load factor of immutable HashSet in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor, hashset, capacity, load-factor

Is there an easy way to initialize initial capacity and load factor of HashSet in Scala? In Java it's very easy, for example:

```
public HashSet set = new HashSet(1 << 8, 0.6f)
```

I'd like to know, if there is any equivalent of this in Scala.

I also know that it's easy to use Javas HashSet instead simply by importing java.util.HashSet, but I'm curious if same is possible with scala.collection.immutable.HashSet

EDIT. 
I've checked from Scala API and HashSet source code, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Since it's immutable, it wouldn't have a variable capacity; the capacity is the same as the size.  Similarly, the load factor in a mutable hashset is used to determine when to re-hash, but in the immutable case re-hashing will never happen.

Comment: Oh, that's true... how I didn't notice that xD.

How does it then work with mutable HashSet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashsets comes with two flawors in scala.

[`mutable.HashSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashSet) is pretty like java `HashSet` and it has 
[`sizeHint` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashSet@sizeHint(size:Int):Unit) which could be used on any (e.g. [empty](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashSet$@empty[A]:scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[A])) collection to resize current table.

[`immutable.HashSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet) has different approach. It is implemented via [hash trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree_(persistent_data_structure)) algorithm instead of [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) so as JimH mentioned methods like `sizeHint` are meaningless for it.